# How to use pdfpages with pagecolor using XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdfpages, pagecolor

I am writing my Master's thesis and I have a LaTeX template for that. I'm using XeTeX compiler. When I try to include a PDF with pdfpages, I get blank pages. I'm aware of the issue with pagecolor (as described in the [package's documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/pdfpages.pdf/0) section 2.5), which the template uses in a few places. However, the fix of putting the first \pagecolor command before \usepackage{pdfpages} does not seem to work for me. The minimal extract from the code looks like this:

Preamble.tex

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{white}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

main.tex

```
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease} % Quick fix for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581907/extra-endgroup-error
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report} %openright
\input{Setup/Statics.tex}
\input{Setup/Preamble.tex}
\input{Setup/Settings.tex}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{Frontmatter/Frontpage.tex}
\pagecolor{white}
\newgeometry{top=2.81cm, bottom=2.75cm, outer=2.5cm, inner=3.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage 
\input{Frontmatter/Copyright.tex}
\clearpage 
\pagestyle{main}
\input{Frontmatter/Approval.tex}
\clearpage 
\input{Frontmatter/Abstract.tex}
\clearpage 
\input{Frontmatter/Acknowledgements.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Chapters/01_Introduction.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/02_Methods.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/03_Results.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/04_Discussion.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]
\cleardoublepage 
\appendix
\includepdf[pages=-]{Backmatter/Graphics_Engines_for_Mixed_Reality.pdf}
\input{Backmatter/Appendix.tex}
\cleartoleftpage
\input{Backmatter/Backpage.tex}

\end{document}
```

I have seen [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47767/how-do-i-add-a-separate-latex-document-as-an-appendix), but as mentioned, the fix from the documentation does not work for me, and the \nopagecolor command is not recognized ([apparently it's not available on XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/how-to-change-the-background-color-only-for-the-current-page)).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: make an example that we can compile to test the issue. You can use example-image.pdf for the includepdf.

Comment: When making the example I found that it works on Overleaf, so it must be an issue with my local setup. Never mind, this is good enough for me for now. Thanks!

Comment: I can reproduce this issue. It seems to be independend of the used TeX-engine but related to `\RequirePackage[2020/02/02]{latexrelease}`. The date (argument of latexrelease) seems to matter too. But so far I don't know what's going wrong. Maybe someone else more knowledgeable in `latexrelease` can help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I believe I found the reason for this issue:

1. On 2020/10/01 LaTeX was released with a new hook management system.
   See https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews32.pdf.
   Concerning the issue you are reporting, the relevant hooks are `shipout/background` and
   `shipout/foreground`.
2. On 2020/10/14 `eso-pic.sty` was updated to be compliant with LaTeX's new hook management system. Since then eso-pic explicitely requests `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-10-01}`. It's not working without LaTeX's new hook management any more.
3. Pdfpages relies on eso-pic. Internally pdfpages forwards all `\includegraphics` commands to eso-pic, and eso-pic stuffs them into LaTeX's new hooks. Therefore you cannot use pdfpages with a LaTeX release early than 2020/10/01 any more.
4. But you are explicitely requesting an early LaTeX release with `\RequirePackage[2020/02/02]{latexrelease}`. And this is the problem.
5. For all of you who are reading the log-files more carefully -- well, I didn't, *grmpf* -- it was all there:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2020-10-01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2020/02/02' is available.
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense, thank you!